# Sublime Text 2 - Problems with HTML automatic indentation

Tags: html, sublimetext2

Every time I type an opening html tag (like `<div>`) then press the Enter key, the cursor automatically inserts an indention on the next line. However I don't want it to be indented since I still have to write the closing tag (actually I press the enter twice and write the closing tag in the third line so I can have an empty line in between). Now I have to press the back button to align the cursor with the opening tag.

I am aware of Sublime Text 2's autocomplete like when you type '<' and Ctrl + Space, a list
of available elements would appear. And when you select one item from the list, the editor would
provide you of both the opening and the closing tag. However, I'm not used to that kind of typing.

So is there a way to turn off this annoying feature of Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 3):

You can disable auto-indentation by setting `auto_indent` to `false`.

In order to do this for the HTML syntax only, go to *Preferences/Settings – More/Syntax Specific – User* and insert the following contents:

```
{
    "auto_indent": false
}
```

This will make the cursor to jump back at column 0 after hitting return.

To make it stay at the column of the opening tag, re-enable `auto_indent` and tweak the indentation settings in `Packages/HTML/Miscellaneous.tmPreferences`. If you aren’t into regular expressions, try to get rid of this file completely.

Comment: It does not work on nested tags. It always places the cursor at the beginning of the next line. What I want is that the cursor should be on the same column as the opening tag.

Comment: Ah, now I get, what you’re trying to achieve :) See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just type the closing `</div>` tag and sublime text will automatically un-indent it for you.